# How to add biweekly periods in a year to a table? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

This SQL Statement is not enough to add the right biweekly periods.
What i want is something like this:

```
Column 1 (period) / Column 2 (start period) / Column 3 (end period)
20160115 / 2016-01-01 / 2016-01-15
20160131 / 2016-01-15 / 2016-01-31
20160215 / 2016-02-01 / 2016-02-15
20160229 / 2016-02-16 / 2016-02-29
```

and so on...

This is what I have now, which is wrong / incomplete.
the value is being inserted correctly in the table columns but the gap is wrong since months don't have the same amount of days

Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

```
    DECLARE @d date= '20020101'
WHILE @d<'20030101'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [TABLE]
        VALUES ((SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @d, 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]), @d, @d, 'Fechado', '1')
        SET @d=DATEADD(DAY,15,@d)
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for an adhoc numbers table, and `union all` for two queries with some date math using `dateadd()`:

```
declare @startdate date = '2016-01-01'
declare @enddate   date = '2016-12-31'

;with cte as (
select top (datediff(month,@startdate,@enddate)+1)
  Month = convert(date,dateadd(month,row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1,@startdate))
from master..spt_values
order by month
)
select 
    Period = convert(char(8), dateadd(day,14,month), 112)
  , PeriodStart = month
  , PeriodEnd = dateadd(day,14,month)
from cte
union all 
select 
    Period = convert(char(8), eomonth(month), 112)
  , PeriodStart = dateadd(day,14,month)
  , PeriodEnd = eomonth(month)
from cte
order by period
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BSYIXW7864

returns:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
|  Period  | PeriodStart | PeriodEnd  |
+----------+-------------+------------+
| 20160115 | 2016-01-01  | 2016-01-15 |
| 20160131 | 2016-01-15  | 2016-01-31 |
| 20160215 | 2016-02-01  | 2016-02-15 |
| 20160229 | 2016-02-15  | 2016-02-29 |
| 20160315 | 2016-03-01  | 2016-03-15 |
| 20160331 | 2016-03-15  | 2016-03-31 |
| 20160415 | 2016-04-01  | 2016-04-15 |
| 20160430 | 2016-04-15  | 2016-04-30 |
| 20160515 | 2016-05-01  | 2016-05-15 |
| 20160531 | 2016-05-15  | 2016-05-31 |
| 20160615 | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-15 |
| 20160630 | 2016-06-15  | 2016-06-30 |
| 20160715 | 2016-07-01  | 2016-07-15 |
| 20160731 | 2016-07-15  | 2016-07-31 |
| 20160815 | 2016-08-01  | 2016-08-15 |
| 20160831 | 2016-08-15  | 2016-08-31 |
| 20160915 | 2016-09-01  | 2016-09-15 |
| 20160930 | 2016-09-15  | 2016-09-30 |
| 20161015 | 2016-10-01  | 2016-10-15 |
| 20161031 | 2016-10-15  | 2016-10-31 |
| 20161115 | 2016-11-01  | 2016-11-15 |
| 20161130 | 2016-11-15  | 2016-11-30 |
| 20161215 | 2016-12-01  | 2016-12-15 |
| 20161231 | 2016-12-15  | 2016-12-31 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Looks like I have a different definition for biweekly. :( for me are two weeks but looks like is just the first 15 days and the rest?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I understand the difference, but I was going off of the desired results at the beginning of the question which indicates _semi-monthly_.

Comment: Yes my rant is more for the language barrier. I can understand semi-monthly and seem like OP want

Comment: My definition of "biweekly" is exactly like yours.

Comment: Your answer made me undertand what I have to do!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function, then call in your query:

Function:

```
create FUNCTION advance_biweekly
(
    @current date
)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    --if it's the first day of month, advance two weeks
    if (DAY(@current) = 1)
        return DATEADD(WEEK, 2, @current)
    else
    --if its last day of month, advance one day
    if (DAY(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @current) + 1, 0)))  = DAY(@current))
        return DATEADD(DAY, 1, @current)
    else
    --else, it's the middle of the month, go to end
        return dateadd(month,((YEAR(@current)-1900)*12)+MONTH(@current)-1,DAY(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @current) + 1, 0)))-1)

    return null

END
GO
```

code:

```
DECLARE @d date= '20020101'
WHILE @d<'20030101'
begin
    set @d = dbo.advance_biweekly(@d)
    print @d
end
```

result:

```
2002-01-15
2002-01-31
2002-02-01
2002-02-15
2002-02-28
2002-03-01
2002-03-15
2002-03-31
2002-04-01
2002-04-15
2002-04-30
2002-05-01
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the other solution easier to me, I still used this logic for another functionality!